# Comparing 4 digits in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I need to compare like
3425 with 2478.
if the 1st digit (from left, 3 and 2) matches it will check the 2nd digit and go on with 4th digit.
IF only 1st digit match assign 1, first 2 match then 2, first three match then 3 and all matches then 4 otherwise 0.

How can I do that in excel? If anyone please give your valuable comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this, but if you're stuck, keep it simple rather than going for an elegant solution.  Just build the formula the same way you describe it.

You can extract the individual digits by treating the numbers like a text string and using LEFT, MID, and RIGHT (or even just MID for each digit).  Use nested IFs to test the sequential digits from the left, either adding 1 for each successive match, or terminating when there is not a match.  Assuming the comparison numbers are in A1 and B1, the result formula in C1 would look like this:

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,1)<>LEFT(B1,1),0,1+IF(MID(A1,2,1)<>MID(B1,2,1),0,1+IF(MID(A1,3,1)<>MID(B1,3,1),0,1+IF(RIGHT(A1,1)<>RIGHT(B1,1),0,1))))
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Testing for "not equal" simplifies the logic of terminating because the formula directly follows your rules.  You could test for "equal", but the formula sequence would become more abstract.

Answer (score 1):

This array formula will iterate the numbers and return the largest matching string:

```
=MAX(IF(LEFT(A1,ROW($A$1:$A$4))=LEFT(B1,ROW($A$1:$A$4)),ROW($A$1:$A$4)))
```

Being an Array Formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]